# Error trying to open newly installed RStudio in OS X 10.10

Tags: r, rstudio, osx-yosemite

Date 7/12/15, Mac, Yosemite OS X 10.10.4

Error message: "R not found: Unable to find R binary by scanning standard locations."

These issues continue even after updating from OS X 10.10.3 to 10.10.4.
Have cleared all cache. Deleted and reinstalled RStudio. 
Called Apple Support who says this is not on their end. 
Anybody knows what this is?

Comment: did you install r itself? rstudio needs to base r preinstalled to work

Comment: I thought it was one or the other! On my last computer I had R already installed before RStudio, but didn't know this was a necessity. Thank you so much!